# Filter out Object keys by Interface in Typescript

Tags: typescript

I have this object that I get as a result from an API:

```
  const item: any = {
    a: 1,
    b: 2,
    c: 3,
  }
```

And I have this interface:

```
  interface Item {
    a: number;
    b: number;
  }
```

I want to make the object fit the interface, and remove keys that don't appear in the interface, the expected result is:

```
  const filteredItem: Item = {
    a: 1,
    b: 2,
  };
```

I want the solution to be dynamic, and not specific to the example I've shown here. Any key that doesn't appear in the interface should be removed from the object.

Comment: this will require a js function and your interface will need to come from a js object.  The function will map through the object and remove the keys that are not present in the object from which the interface was derived. Is that okay?

Comment: coming back to this tomorrow

Comment: Hey @wonderflame , came across a few solutions that use a "dummy object", looking for a more direct way (if even possible), but thank you!

Comment: Typescript doesn't affect the runtime behavior. It's not going to be possible

Comment: @wonderflame I see, well then if you want to share your solution it would be great, for the sake of future visitors of this question as well :)

Comment: Does [this](https://tsplay.dev/WkapjN) work?

Comment: @wonderflame, it does but sadly doesn't answer my need, wonder if there is a way to derive the array of keys from a type/class/interface in a "clean" way. Maybe not for the same reason you've mentioned above.

Comment: This is essentially impossible without a list of keys at runtime, or something like it. See the linked question and its answers.